# How to fully justify text in elsarticle

Tags: elsarticle, ragged2e, justification

[image]
[image]

How can i justify all the texts in this paper. This is Elsevier article which is probably converted from IEEE format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you perhaps disable hyphenation in some way? In my experiment the word is split as expected. Please add the whole document preamble as code and not as an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of just typing

```
... areas like Psychological, ...
```

type

```
... areas like Psy\-cho\-log\-i\-cal, ...
```

This will define the breaking points for TeX. If you're using that term more regularly (rather than just at a single spot), you can add `\hyphenation{Psy-cho-log-i-cal}` to your preamble to define the breaking points globally.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

To prevent (or disable) hyphenation in text rows, add `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` to your preamble in a single-language document.

Comment: I suspect that the OP *has* `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, which would be the cause of the problem.